# Drupal Coding Standards for Commercial Use?

Tags: drupal

I'm busy working on book/document that will be used for commercial use. I want to include the Drupal Coding Standards in this as the one section deals with drupal in depth. Am I allowed to copy and paste the coding standards and place it in my book as an appendix? Must I get permission?

Answer (score 3):

Just an FYI: The contents of the drupal.org handbook pages are CC-SA licensed (see [the drupal.org licensing page.](http://drupal.org/node/14307) Details are there.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest it looks like a bit of a minefield and I would get a lawyer involved. The Drupal coding standards are based on the PEAR coding standards which have [several licensing options](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/faq.devs.php#faq.licenses).